# Send Single File to different location through custom disassembler

Tags: biztalk

I am getting a file in receive location and I want to send that file to a repository location as well as want to save that file in database ? I want to done this  through custom disassembler ?
Please provide any useful link by which I can get my requiremnet.

Comment: why can't you use two send port using same subscription to send these messages out?

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk has a publish-subcribe architecture, which means that whenever something is published to the message box, you can use 1-N subscribers.

This means the easiest scenario would be to use two send ports:

1. One to send the file to the repository location (FILE adapter)
2. One to send the file to the database (WCF-SQL adapter or in case of BizTalk 2006 R1, the SQL adapter)

Both would subscribe to the same input message and would need a different outbound map on their send port to map to the correct schemas for your needs.

The subscription is the send port filter, where you can either point to the receive port (BTS.ReceivePortName although this is not a good practice) or to the BTS.MessageType (better approach).

Hope this helps you out!